# mySql :: error in general variable error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, navicat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL - Syntax Error in Strored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134105/mysql-syntax-error-in-strored-procedure)

Thanks, but if use variable :::::like this  :

```
 IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT ReferenceID as ExistedRefID  FROM filesrefrences WHERE RefrenceKey= pRefrenceKey) THEN
        INSERT INTO filesrefrences(RefrenceKey, RefrenceCount)
        VALUES(pRefrenceKey,1);
       SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
    ELSE
        UPDATE filesrefrences
        SET RefrenceCount= RefrenceCount+1
        WHERE ReferenceID= ExistedRefID;
        SELECT ExistedRefID;
    END IF
```

it refers executing error that **ExistedRefID** is uknown, how could i solve this

Comment: Don't add same question again you can get answer on the same question. You r last question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134105/mysql-syntax-error-in-strored-procedure

Comment: I have already given answer on your last question check it

Comment: sorry but i add it as an answer for the last Q. anyway I'm very grateful for your answer

Comment: Remove this question from here and communicate on your last question for thew same.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
insert into filesreferences (RefrenceKey, RefrenceCount) values (pRefrenceKey, 1)
    on duplicate key update RefrenceCount= RefrenceCount+1;
```

Comment: but RefrenceKey is not primary key...  does it valid

Comment: ah; it helps to give your actual table structure when you ask questions.  it should still work if RefrenceKey is a unique index.

Comment: Ok.. I will make it as unique index ... thankyou